# Jquery appending in front of div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

So I'm using Jquery Drag/Drop to drag and drop something onto a dashboard. I want to now drag anything that I have dropped onto the dashboard out of the dashboard in order to destroy it/remove it from the dashboard.

I've tried adding a class to the thing that is dropped onto the dashboard and then tried adding a draggable to that, but the drag is not working, I think because when I append the element to the dashboard it appears behind the dashboard(the colours are a little faded).

Here is my code-

```
    $(".draggable").draggable({helper:'clone'});
    $("#favouritesDashboard").droppable({
        accept:".draggable",
        drop: function(event,ui) {
            var toDrop = $(ui.draggable).clone();
            //create smaller version
            $(toDrop).addClass("inDashBoard");

            $(this).append(toDrop);
        }
    });
   $(".inDashBoard").click(function(){
    console.log("clicking elem in dashboard");
   });
```

I've replaced the second draggable with a click, the console.log never prints, suggesting that what I think is going on is actually going on.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the nature of event binding / listeners in jQuery.

The elements you want to trigger a click event on do not exist when the page is loaded, they are added dynamically. So to ensure that your method is attached to new elements that match the selector you should use "on" or "live"

```
$(".inDashBoard").on( "click", function(){
   console.log("clicking elem in dashboard");
});
```

Comment: does the same structure work for draggable? i.e. can I go 
$(".inDashBoard").bind("draggable",function(){....

Comment: also, I don't think that was the issue- I just tried that and it's still not console logging properly

Comment: `bind` does NOT account for future elements. `on()` and `delegate()` do

Comment: @charlietfl right you are! Sorry about that. Updated answer to "on", "live" also I believe does the same thing.

Comment: your syntax for `on()` currently won't delegate handler for future element either. `live()` is deprecated

Comment: @charlietfl right but there's no way to know what version of jquery the question is using ;) Nah, just kidding - you're right of course. I'm not going to edit my answer thou since someone has already left an answer with "on" correctly

Answer (score 0):

Use on for late binding http://api.jquery.com/on/ .

```
$(document).on('click', '.inDashBoard', function(){
    console.log("clicking elem in dashboard");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```
$(".inDashBoard").live('click', function(){
    console.log("clicking elem in dashboard");
});
```